# How to embed a PApplet in javafx?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, javafx, processing

So I got my Processing code working in java. But now I want to embed it in JavaFX for my GUI. How can I do so?
I tried using the following code but it does not seem to work.

```
 package testprocessing;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import java.util.concurrent.*;
import processing.core.*;

public class JavaFxApplet extends Application {
    private PApplet applet = new MyProcessingSketch();
    private Dimension appletSize;

    @Override public void init() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        applet.init();

        FutureTask<Dimension> sizingTask = new FutureTask<>(() ->
            applet.getRootPane().getPreferredSize()
        );
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(sizingTask);
        appletSize = sizingTask.get();
    }

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
            swingNode.setContent(applet.getRootPane())
        );

        stage.setScene(
            new Scene(
                new Group(swingNode),
                appletSize.getWidth(), appletSize.getHeight(),
                Color.BLACK
            )
        );
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override public void stop() {
        applet.stop();
        applet.destroy();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         launch(args);
     }
}
```

I get error at getRootPane(). Can you suggest an alternative for it?

Comment: "Getting an error" doesn't mean anything. Java is very good at telling you what caused the error. So, what caused the error? What does the compiler say? What stack trace is printed? What happens, what do you expect to happen? Give information.

Answer (score 5):

### Background

Introduced in **Processing 3** was a JavaFX rendering mode that makes it possible to include JavaFX in our sketches. Rather than creating our own JavaFX window from scratch and then embedding our sketch within it, we can **modify the window that is constructed by the PApplet class** when it is initialised in JavaFX mode, adding new JavaFX elements therein.

During initialisation in JavaFX mode, the PApplet class creates a `javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas` object and adds this as a child to a `javafx.scene.layout.StackPane` object. Then, a `javafx.scene.Scene` object is constructed with the *stackPane* object as a parameter. Finally, the PApplet class creates a `javafx.stage.Stage` object and sets its scene to the *scene* object, to give us our PApplet instance - the sketch.

So in terms of JavaFX elements, the PApplet window is initialised with four elements in the following hierarchy: `Stage > Scene > StackPane > Canvas`, where the *canvas* is the graphical canvas of the sketch (ie. the object that Processing draws to).

**To create our own GUI**, we can add any `javafx.scene.Node` object (this is the superclass of JavaFX graphical elements) to the *stackPane* object. Alternatively you could construct a new *Scene*, add the Processing's canvas to it, and replace the existing *Scene* of the *Stage*.

---

### What doesn't seem to work

Without specifying the rendering mode, Processing defaults to `JAVA2D` mode. In this mode, the PApplet class creates a PApplet instance with `java.awt` versions of the canvas and window (a `java.awt.Canvas` and `java.awt.Frame` respectively). In theory, it is possible to cast the `java.awt.Frame` to a `javax.swing.JFrame`, embed this in a `javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode` object and finally add this to a JavaFX stage. However, I haven't been able to get this to work.

There are also the `P2D` & `P3D` modes. In these modes, the canvas is a  `com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow` object. Again, I have tried to embed this in a Swing Node, with the help of a `com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel`, but it has not proven successful.

---

### Implementation

Initialise your sketch in Processing's `FX2D` rendering mode in the call to `size()`:

`size([width], [height], FX2D);`

We can then expose the four JavaFX elements that were created during initialisation by repeated casting:

```
final PSurfaceFX FXSurface = (PSurfaceFX) surface;

final Canvas canvas = (Canvas) FXSurface.getNative();
final StackPane stackPane = (StackPane) canvas.getParent();
final Scene scene = canvas.getScene();
final Stage stage = (Stage) canvas.getScene().getWindow();
```

We now have an option as to how we add our JavaFX elements:

**1) Add to the existing stackPane**

We can add JavaFX elements (`javafx.scene.Node` objects) to the *stackPane* that was created during initialisation with the following method:

```
stackPane.getChildren().add(Node node);
```

**2) Create a new scene (recommended)**

Alternatively (recommended, unless you want a stackPane as a top-level aligner), we can create a new scene object (rather than using the *scene* and *stackPane* objects that were created during initialisation) and add JavaFX elements to this.

```
Scene newscene = new Scene(new Group(canvas)); // simple group containing only the Processing canvas
stage.setScene(Scene scene);
```

During initialisation, the *canvas*' dimensions are binded to those of the *stackPane*. If we wish to change the size of the Processing canvas within the window during runtime, we must include the following:

```
canvas.widthProperty().unbind();
canvas.heightProperty().unbind();
```

Now we can freely call `canvas.setHeight()` and `canvas.setWidth()` to resize to Processing canvas within the JavaFX window (the stage).

### Example

Let's add a `javafx.scene.control.MenuBar` to the window. Note that I am initialising our JavaFX elements within the `initSurface()` method rather than doing so within the `setup()` method, as it's safer.

In this example, the *stackPane* is replaced with a `javafx.scene.layout.VBox`, first, so that the menubar sits atop of the *canvas* and second, to ensure the *stage* is the correct height (the sum of the menuBar height and canvas height) at launch.

```
@Override
public void settings() {
    size(500, 500, FX2D);
}

@Override
protected PSurface initSurface() {

    PSurface surface = super.initSurface();

    final PSurfaceFX FXSurface = (PSurfaceFX) surface;
    final Canvas canvas = (Canvas) FXSurface.getNative(); // canvas is the processing drawing
    final Stage stage = (Stage) canvas.getScene().getWindow(); // stage is the window

    stage.setTitle("Processing/JavaFX Example");
    canvas.widthProperty().unbind();
    canvas.heightProperty().unbind();

    final MenuItem menuItem1 = new MenuItem("Fill green");
    menuItem1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            noLoop();
            background(0, 255, 0); // Fills the canvas green on click
        }
    });

    final MenuItem menuItem2 = new MenuItem("Exit");
    menuItem2.setOnAction(actionEvent -> exit()); // Exit PApplet on click

    final Menu menu = new Menu("Menu");
    menu.getItems().add(menuItem1);
    menu.getItems().add(menuItem2);

    final MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    menuBar.getMenus().add(menu);

    final VBox vBox = new VBox(menuBar, canvas); // Menubar will sit on top of canvas
    final Scene newscene = new Scene(vBox); // Create a scene from the elements
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            stage.setScene(newscene); // Replace the stage's scene with our new one.
        }
    });
    return surface;
}

@Override
public void draw() {
    background(50);
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    strokeWeight(5);
    stroke(255, 5, 5);
    line(0, 0, width, 0); // shows us that window is the correct dimensions
    line(0, height, width, height); // shows us that window is the correct dimensions
    noStroke();
    ellipse(100, 100, 200, 200);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    ellipse(100, 200, 200, 200);
    fill(0, 0, 255);
    ellipse(100, 300, 200, 200);
}
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

Comment: Also see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52709779/java-processing-3-paplet-in-javafx-scene-as-fxnode/52782409#52782409](this) answer about embedding a PApplet within a stage loaded from an FXML file.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to get the applet's root pane? Just add the applet to a JPanel, then add the JPanel to your SwingNode:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(applet);
swingNode.setContent(panel)
```

Comment: swingNode.setContent(applet) gives Incompatible type:PAapley cannot be converted into JComponent

Comment: * PApplet cannot be converted to JComponent

Comment: thank you! That solved the problem. However i am now getting a runtime error as follows:

Comment: Exception in Application start method
Exception in Application stop method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: @sj66 If you're having a separate issue, then post a new question with an updated [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: although the applet window opens it does not show the  contents on the applet. It only displays a blank screen

Comment: @sj66 Then please post a separate question with you updated code in the form of an MCVE.

Comment: I have done so. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514793/exception-in-thread-animation-thread-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-width?noredirect=1#comment45348040_28514793