# Processing 3 triangle not showing in Javafx 8 Window tab

Tags: java, javafx, processing

Hello ive trying to get javafx8 to work 
Witn processing  3 on windows 10 java 8 eclipse latest version ive tried following this 
Tutorial [Java Processing 3 PAplet in JavaFX scene as FXNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52709779/java-processing-3-paplet-in-javafx-scene-as-fxnode/52782409?noredirect=1#comment101518639_52782409)

But im getting this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = main
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.checkEventThread(Application.java:443)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Window.getScreen(Window.java:403)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.setBounds(WindowStage.java:289)
    at javafx.stage.Window$TKBoundsConfigurator.apply(Window.java:1292)
    at javafx.stage.Window.applyBounds(Window.java:1182)
    at javafx.stage.Window.centerOnScreen(Window.java:283)
    at processing.javafx.PSurfaceFX.placeWindow(PSurfaceFX.java:574)
    at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10849)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10562)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10544)
    at processingfxnew.SirpenskiTriangle.main(SirpenskiTriangle.java:13)
```

And the processing sketch isnt appearing 
In the javafx windows tab im not sure how to fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaFX has an "event thread" that is responsible for updating the GUI, responding to button clicks, etc (i.e. any GUI operation).

If you try to update the GUI **in any way** on a thread other than the JavaFX event thread, you will get this error. To fix it either :

- Call your code from a method invoked by the event thread naturally (preferred) - i.e. attach it to a `button.setOnAction(event -> {updateGui()})` for example.
- Wrap it in a call to `Platform.runLater()` - i.e. `Platform.runLater(() -> updateGui());` This will post your call to the event thread. Be careful with this, however, as it is often abused to make messy code work.

Comment: so why does that post say that it will load by default, is it not true anymore or can i make the button force click itself

Comment: I can't comment on that post. If you want to make a button click from inside Java code, you can call `button.fire();` which will simulate a click on the button.